# code to increment a alphanumeric value for each run of method in ranorex

Tags: ranorex

Am working on Ranorex Tool, I have a scenario like I need to generate an alpha-numeric value(Eg:AAA123) for each run of method. here string is constant and the numeric value should increment by 1 for each run of method.Can anyone please help me. thanks in advance

Comment: do you know the numbers and do they change with each test run?
for instance are the number always going to be say 0- 100 each time you run it? if so the easy way is to put the method as a specific test case and simply do a simple data binding to it with a different value for each iteration

Answer (score 0):

If your string is FIXED, then you can first split the characters part and numeric part. 
Then you can cast numeric part to int and increment that portion.
At last, concat these two again.

Let me know if you need code sample.